# TinyMCE : image selection on onMouseUp (wordpress / contenteditable)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, dom-events, contenteditable

I'm working on a custom TinyMCE editor for Wordpress. One of the feature of Wordpress is Image Caption, which put a `<div>` around an `<img>` tag.

I'm trying to achieve the following : when a user click on an `<img>`, I want to get the parent `<div>` selected.

For this, I've added a custom handler on onMouseDown dispatcher that select the caption `<div>`.

```
ed.onMouseDown.addToTop(function(ed, e) {

  // Check if it is an image or image with caption
  var parents = ed.dom.getParents(e.target,'div.amu_container');

  if ( parents.length > 0 ) {
    var container = parents[0];

    // Correct selection to amu_container
    ed.selection.select(container);

    // Prevent default
    tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(e);
  }
});
```

All works fine : after all onMouseDown handlers, the caption `<div>` is well selected.

And then on `mouseUp` all works fine on FF, but on Chrome, when all `onMouseUp` handlers are finished, the `<img>` gets selected, loosing the precedent selection of caption `<div>`.

However `mouseUp` event is `defaultPrevented`...

Any thoughts ?

**Edit :**
Here is a jsfiddle reproducing my issue : http://jsfiddle.net/nH8fj/5/

When user click on image or container, the whole `<div>` should be selected. On step by step debug, the selection is effectively done but then only the image is selected.

I'm on Chromium 16.0.912.36 linux, the bug is reproducible on latest Chrome windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.target` works on webkit, but does not work for IE. There you will have to use  `e.srcElement`. Maybe there is a similar issue with Chrome here.

I found a bug report for Chrome here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15848

Comment: Thanks for the IE advise. In this case I use the tinyMCE framework and I hope this misbehavior is prevented like in jQuery.

For my issue : I've check `e.target`, it is OK on mouseUp.

This really seems to be a default behavior not prevented : if I execute JS step by step, until the last step the selection is OK (the whole `<div>`), and then the selection is reduced to `<img>` only.

I'll try to reproduce the bug on jsfiddle.

Comment: jsfiddle is a good thing here, please give us your chrome version too

Comment: I've edited my post with a jsfiddle and some explanations : http://jsfiddle.net/nH8fj/5/

Comment: took me some time, but here is a workaround i came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/nU2wq/